# Performing rigid translation of polygon using GeoTools Java API?

Tags: java, geotools, translation

I've been spending some days trying to find the best way to do a "rigid translate" of a polygon in a certain direction and distance, without much luck. To provide an example, consider translate like moving a polygon on 30 degrees south, for 500 meters.

Is there any API in Java GeoTools that you have used successfully to do such moving of a polygon?

If not for the polygon as a whole in one operation, I can do a single point translation for each point of the polygon, if no better solution can be found. I don't need to do this real time, so I have processing time to spend to do this.

The approach I'm following so far is of calculating the shifting on the single point as for this link to the [geodetic calculator](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html)

In the specific the part called:

*Generate location away from a point*

```
    `GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator();
    // mind, this is lon/lat
    calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(45.4644, 9.1908);
    calc.setDirection(90 /* azimuth */, 200 /* distance */);
    Point2D dest = calc.getDestinationGeographicPoint();
    System.out.println("Longitude: " + dest.getX() + " Latitude: " + dest.getY());`
```

Comment: Assuming a Cartesian coordinate system, you need only calculate *dx* and *dy* values from bearing and distance, to be applied to all vertices.

Comment: JTS affine transformation translate - https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/util/AffineTransformation.html#translate-double-double-

Comment: @IanTurton the affine transform I need to compare with the geodetic calculator to see if it works with a geometry, as if I have to calculate for each point of the polygon, it may be too much calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JTS affine transformation if (and only if) you are working in a cartesian coordinate system, so if you are using a geographic coordinate system (i.e lat,lon) you will first need to reproject to a local crs. Then you can apply a translate in metres and finally reproject back to geographic coordinates.

```
Polygon p = GenerateRandomData.createRandomPolygon(5);
System.out.println(p);
Point c = p.getCentroid();
double x = c.getCoordinate().x;
double y = c.getCoordinate().y;
String code = "AUTO:42001," + y + "," + x;
// System.out.println(code);
CoordinateReferenceSystem auto = CRS.decode(code);
// System.out.println(auto);
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, auto);
MathTransform inverseTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(auto, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
Geometry cp = JTS.transform(p, transform);
// System.out.println(cp);
AffineTransformation affine = new AffineTransformation();
affine = affine.translate(5000, 0);
Geometry tp = affine.transform(cp);
// System.out.println(tp);
Geometry np = JTS.transform(tp, inverseTransform);
System.out.println(np);
```

Will produce the following (moving the polygon 5km East):

**Update**

If you are working with a distance and bearing then you need to calculate the X, Y offset (here I'm doing the whole circle to check my code):

```
 double distance = 20000; // 20km
    for (int i = 45; i <= 360; i += 45) {
      double bearing = 360 * (i / 360.0);
      double rBearing = Math.toRadians(bearing);
      double dx = distance * Math.cos(rBearing);
      double dy = distance * Math.sin(rBearing);
      AffineTransformation affine = new AffineTransformation();
      affine = affine.translate(dx, dy);
      Geometry tp = affine.transform(cp);
      Geometry np = JTS.transform(tp, inverseTransform);
      System.out.println(np);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ian Turton, so far by points I get similar result, but it is by points transform that is far less elegant and optimized by your approach. I'm going to test the same. Thanks, I will update once I have tested.

Comment: Sorry @Ian Turton, but the 5000 is a distance, while zero is not the bearing in degrees, is a distance as well on the other coordinate, am I right ?

Comment: that is an X and Y distance

Comment: see the answer I posted to myself :).

Answer (score 0):

quick update on this: at the end I came up writing the method below.  I'm still investigating on applying the affine transform to have a better and more elegant solution, but in the meanwhile this code does the job.

```
/**
 * Translate a source geometry by distance and bearing
 * @param source is the source geometry
 * @param bearing is the bearing in degrees
 * @param distance is the distance in meters
 * @return a geometry that is the translation of the passed in geometry
 */
private Geometry translateGeometry(Geometry source, long distance, int bearing) throws Exception{
    Geometry translatedPolygon = null;

      GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

      Coordinate[] translatedPolygonCoordinates  = new Coordinate[unionGeometry.getCoordinates().length];
      GeodeticCalculator geodeticCalculator = new GeodeticCalculator();
      Point2D aDestination = null;
      Coordinate aCoordinate = null;

       for(int i=0; i < unionGeometry.getCoordinates().length; i++){           
              // mind, this is lon/lat
              //Lon = x
              //Lat = y
              geodeticCalculator.setStartingGeographicPoint(unionGeometry.getCoordinates()[i] .getX(), unionGeometry.getCoordinates()[i] .getY()); 
              geodeticCalculator.setDirection(bearing /* azimuth */, distance /* distance */);
              aDestination = geodeticCalculator.getDestinationGeographicPoint();
              aCoordinate = new Coordinate(aDestination.getX(), aDestination.getY());
              translatedPolygonCoordinates[i] = aCoordinate;               
       }

      LinearRing ring = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(translatedPolygonCoordinates);
      LinearRing holes[] = null; // use LinearRing[] to represent holes
      Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(ring, holes);
      translatedPolygon = polygon;

     return translatedPolygon;      
}
```

Comment: This will probably give the wrong answer for large polygons or large offsets as you aren't accounting for the curved nature of the Earth

Comment: Yes, I agree, in fact I'm still looking on a better way to do this, unfortunately I presume I will still have to stay on single points loop but accounting for transformation somehow, as I need bearing degrees and I cannot find any other solution so far. Not sure if converting y into radiants or something like that may help. By now I know my polygons will not have holes (although I could handle them) and they will always be small enough to not care about curved earth.